Clerk NextJS Causing Multiple Page Redirects
I'm using clerk/nextjs 5.1.5 in my next 14.2.4 app with middleware.
My home page is not protected by middleware and is publicly accessible. I want my home page to be indexed by Google.
However, it isn't getting indexed by Google because Clerk is causing too many redirects when the Google bot goes to my home page. Has anyone run into this problem with Clerk before?
Google Test Live Url
Same issue but using the Lighthouse Chrome Extension
I tried:

Changing my Clerk NEXT_PUBLIC_CLERK_PUBLISHABLE_KEY,CLERK_SECRET_KEY keys to a new Clerk Application in case my Clerk Application was outdated

Adjusting my Clerk middleware  Current Clerk Middleware



you should use normal clerk middleware and the page u dont want to be protected you can do this:
<signedOut>
  <Home />
</signedOut>


Thanks, but my home page is not protected. Anyone can go to my website and view the home page. The problem is when the Google bot goes to my home page, Clerk causes a redirect error (see the "Google Test Live Url" link I posted in my original question), causing my home page to be excluded from Google indexing
